# Is the _HAVE_BOOST macro a built-in in C++? Where does it come from?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm reading a piece of code that seems like it optionally uses the C++ Boost library. It is as follows:

```
#ifdef _HAVE_BOOST
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#endif
```

Later on in the code, there are several statements that depend on this "_HAVE_BOOST". I presume that _HAVE_BOOST is simply a flag that is set to true, if the C++ library is properly imported.

Is the "_HAVE_BOOST" flag a built-in part of C++ ifdef syntax? That is, I tried Googling for this flag but didn't find any documentation. Also, at the head of the file, no `#include<boost>` is present. It looks like this boost functionality is deprecated throughout the file -- would _HAVE_BOOST be set to true if this `#include<boost>` were added?

Is there a list or documentation somewhere for describing the kinds of capital letters that go along with #ifdef?

Comment: `#ifdef` just checks if a symbol is defined.

Comment: I edited your title to one that actually describes something. People finding this question in their search results will thank me.

Comment: When is _HAVE_BOOST defined? Is it built-in? What causes it to be defined?

Comment: You can define symbols on the compiler command line (often `-D`). It could be defined in a different file before this file is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I presume that _HAVE_BOOST is simply a flag that is set to true...

`#ifdef _HAVE_BOOST` does not test whether `_HAVE_BOOST` is `true`; It test whether such [preprocessor macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is defined at all, regardless of the value.

> ...if the C++ library is properly imported.

Yes, considering the context, this particular macro is probably meant to signify, whether Boost is available or not and thus, whether it's possible to depend on it.

> Is there a list or documentation somewhere for describing the kinds of capital letters that go along with #ifdef?

Macros can be defined with either `#define` directive in a header file or, in the compilation command (See the -D option for [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) for example). Compilers may also [predefine](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) some macros as well.

Any header file can define macros. You should usually be able to find which macros may be defined by reading the documentation, or if you don't have documentation, by reading the header files themselves.

> would _HAVE_BOOST be set to true if this #include were added?

I find it unlikely that it would be defined in `<boost>` itself. After all, testing if Boost is available after you try to include it would be rather pointless.

> When is _HAVE_BOOST defined?

You should ask that from the person who wrote the code. Another question to ponder is, is it defined at all? If it isn't, then the code between the ifdefs is removed by the preprocessor.

My crystal ball tells me that it's probably supposed to be defined by some sort of configuration script for the build process. For example, [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Generic-Headers.html) has a macro that will define a preprocessor macro `HAVE_header-file` if a header exists. Note the lack of underscore at the beginning.

Comment: Good, complete answer

Answer (score 1):

this just means that if you define a preprocessor macro "_HAVE_BOOST" the compiler will include boost/random.hpp. Like this:

```
#define _HAVE_BOOST
#ifdef _HAVE_BOOST
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#endif
```

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) for more details about preprocessor directives.

Comment: #define _HAVE_BOOST does not exist in the file. Is this flag built-in?

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler supports c++11, it will have `<random>` support.

With some clever use of indirect includes and typedefs (or `using` statements ?!) it could be made to work with or without boost for random.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is _HAVE_BOOST a macro built into C++? It is not previously defined in the file.

Comment: Asking whether "_HAVE_BOOST [is] a macro built into C++" is like asking whether the Greek national holidays are part of the Spanish constitution. I assumed your question was mostly about "Later on in the code, there are several statements that depend on this". Sorry for interpreting the question a bit strange. In my defense, the question was also a bit strange :)